# Can't Use Ubuntu 20.04 in Oracle VM Box on Ubuntu Host

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on Oracle VM Box on Ubuntu 20.04 host machine, when I first installed every thing went well, I also downloaded guest-additions etc. Next time whenever I start this VM, it doesn't start at all, it is just booting to a blank page.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the log-file.
https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/virtualbox-log-files-v2
Possibly a resource is missing or it is waiting for something or there is a write-protection.

I always had problems with the package from the Ubuntu-Server. Remove the package.
Install the package from the Website.
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

In my case, this solves every problem. Give it a try.